Multitask learning with multi dataset
How can I train a model to perform multiple tasks simultaneously using multiple datasets, but only have labeled data for each task individually.
I combined two datasets into a comment format with a task type as a task requirement. During the training phase, I used this task type as a condition for the model to calculate the loss for each task and the total loss is the sum of the two losses. Is it ok, I tried it but not effective. Is this approach ok and reasonable???

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
